# array within a structure in c

Tags: c, structure

This is my code. `main` should have only calling function. `testcases()` call the test cases run through the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"conio.h"
int main()
{
    testcases();
}
struct test {
    int a[10];
} testDB[5] = {
    {1,2,3,4,5,6},
    {7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4}
};

void testcases()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    displaytest(testDB[i].a);
}

displaytest(char *a)
{
    int i=0;
    while(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I want to display both the arrays. But I am getting only first indexes. 
Can anyone help ?

Comment: `displaytest(char *a)` --> `void displaytest(int *a)` and put prototype. BTW `{7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4}` : STOP at `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your passed parameter is not appropriate;

```
displaytest(char *a) --> void displaytest(int *a)
```

EDIT: Your while loop won't work, as stated in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can not check like this `while(a[i]!='\0')`

You have to pass the size of the array as 2nd parameter.

```
void displaytest(int *a, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size/sizeof(int))
    {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

While calling, you can call like this...

```
displaytest(testDB[i].a, sizeof(testDB[i].a));
```